# All-day events added to a calendar from a service account appear on the google calendar website but not on the android phone app. Timed-events work

Tags: google-calendar-api

I have created a service account and shared a calendar to the service account with "make changes and manage sharing" permissions.

After I add ALL-DAY events to that calendar via the api, they appear in my calendar when I access it through a web browser. But they are not appearing on my android phone.

However, TIMED-EVENTS work fine. I can add a timed event via the service account and it appears in both my web browser and my phone.

One other note - I can add an all-day event via the web browser (as my user) and it appears as an all day event on my phone.
I am using the python api.
https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/concepts/events-calendars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this. For all-day events to appear on the android app you must set the end date to the day after the start date. This is not a requirement for all-day events to display when viewed in the browser, it works both ways.

Requiring an all day event to end on the day after and the difference in behavior is unintuative. There is no mention of the correct way in their documentation. And no error is thrown when the dates are the same. https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/concepts/events-calendars